# Javascript execution timing - ensure synchronous flow, not just order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asynchronous, css-transitions

I am working with JavaScript (Jquery) trying to run some operations in order. In my real code, I have a function I run on `.ready()` to initiate some variables. As part of this flow I read in some data from *local storage* to remove elements which were removed in a previous visit. The elements which I remove have a css transition class applied. When the page first loads, I do not want these animations to occur, so I require that the `<body>` element has the `class="fully-loaded"` applied in my CSS for transition to work. I am trying to add the `fully-loaded` class only after I know all of the additions and everything else is loaded. I have tried setting up multiple `.ready()` statements, using queues, etc. in order to control the order or execution.

While I think I have things running in order, the initiation function does not seem to be complete before I run the script to add the `fully-loaded` class. I am pasting a mini version of my code which exhibits the same problem. **My question is:** How can I ensure that anything run as part of my initiation function `init()` complete before I run the `addClass` call?

### HTML body:

```
<body>
<section id="secA">    <p>Sec A</p>    </section>
<section id="secB">    <p>Sec B</p>    </section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
//$(document).ready(    Tester.init()   );
//$(document).ready(    $("body").addClass('fully-loaded')  );

//$(document).ready(    Tester.init()   );
$.when(Tester.init()).done(function(){
    $("body").addClass('fully-loaded');
    console.log("Desired Order: 4");
});
</script>    

</body>
```

### JavaScript in another file

```
var Tester = (function() {

    function init() {
        initEvents();
    }

    function initEvents(){       
        console.log("Desired Order: 1");
        setTimeout(
            '$("#secA").remove(); console.log("Desired Order: 2");',
            2000
        );
        console.log("Desired Order: 3");      
    }

    return { init : init };    
})();
```

## CSS Code

```
section {   width:200px;   height:200px;     position:absolute;}

#secA   {   background-color:green;     }
#secB   {   background-color:red;       }

section:nth-of-type(1)      {   top: 0;     left: 0;    }
section:nth-of-type(2)      {   top: 0;     left: 50%;  }

.fully-loaded section {
    -webkit-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2.5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

I think in my real code that there is something that is taking a bit of time which is async like the setTimeout. *Desired Action: 4* occurs before *Desired Action: 2* How do I make `$("body").addClass('fully-loaded');` wait until everything started by `Tester.init()` is complete in a general way?

Comment: You can't keep the order of 2..3, it will be 3..2... other than that http://jsfiddle.net/M4gcX/1/

Comment: Your usage of `when` is buggy because the `init` method is not returning a promise object

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ah, I thought there had to be some type of call back or reference; I didn't see anything like that in the example I was working from. I tried making changes using your fiddle. 2 now executes before 4, but the transition is still there when it should not be, meaning the class is still being added before the item is removed.